# Does a function distribute over lists or does it commute with them?

Tags: terminology, programming-languages, lists

Assume that we have an operation $f$ such that
$$
f([a_0,\ldots, a_n])= [f(a_0),\ldots,f(a_n)]
$$

Do we say that $f$ distributes over lits or do we say it commutes with lists?
Which one is the correct way of expressing this property?

How about the following? 
What do we say for the relation between $f$ and $\vec{a} = a_0,\ldots,a_n$?
$$
f(g(\vec{a})) = g(f(\vec{a})) = g(f(a_0),\ldots,f(a_n))
$$

Comment: I don't have a reference on hand, but a dim memory suggests "component-wise function". If I had to choose between distributive and commutative, I'd go with distributive.

Comment: @Luke, now I have to decide between three in place of two, nice job. ;)

Comment: $f$ has a different type on the left and right hand side of the equation – unless it is polymorphic. I'd go with distributive, too.

Comment: As @DaveClarke points out: $f_{\mathrm{list}}([a_0,\dots, a_n]) = [f_{\mathrm{element}}(a_0),\ldots,f_{\mathrm{element}}(a_n)]$.  So I'd say, "$f_{\mathrm{list}}$ _maps_ $f_{\mathrm{element}}$ _over_ lists."  I think we also say that any function that maps over lists is _linear_ with respect to the list concatenation (addition) operation because $f_{\mathrm{list}}(a+b) = f_{\mathrm{list}}(a) + f_{\mathrm{list}}(b)$.  `map` is what it's actually called in most programming languages too, so bonus.

Comment: Suggestion "componentwise" by @Luke seems in line with suggestion by [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise#Componentwise_operations) (taking the difference between operations and functions for granted). Some people seem to say it is an elementwise function.